# C/C++ PLSA libraries

Tags: c++, math, libraries

I need a library that implements PLSA algorithm.
Possibly I'm looking for a C/C++ implementation, but other language will be good anyway. 
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used the algorithm, but googling for it let me to [this implementation in python](http://www.mblondel.org/journal/2010/06/13/lsa-and-plsa-in-python/) and [this one in Matlab](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/).

Comment: Thank you so much CharlesB!

I hope someone else can also suggest me C++ implementations!!

Comment: I'm glad you found my answer helpful; don't forget to vote it up!